# Django autocomplete - request.is_ajax() always returns false

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

New to Django. Trying to set up a page which has a text box that supports autocomplete. I referred to this [post](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/) for guidance. For some reason, `request.is_ajax()` always returns `false`.

**urls.py for the main app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^search_assist/', include('search_assist.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py for the search_assist app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.search_assist, name='search_assist'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def search_assist(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        states = State.objects.filter(state_name_full__icontains = q )[:20]
        results = []
        for state in states:
            state_json = {}
            state_json['id'] = state.id
            state_json['label'] = state.state_name_full
            state_json['value'] = state.state_name_full
            results.append(state_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "gif_alpha_test/header.html" %}
  <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="sassist">Search Assist: </label>
      <input type="text" id="sassist">
  </div>
```

header.html has the following jQuery function.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    assist();
});
function assist(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

            $("#sassist").autocomplete({
                source: "/search_assist/",
                minLength: 2,
            });});
        }
</script>
```

I have seen few other posts on a similar note but the comments / responses on those posts didn't help.

Any ideas on why request.is_ajax() always returns false? Appreciate the help.

Comment: You are trying to access `source: "/search_assist/"` but the url doesn't have that endpoint `url(r'^$', views.search_assist, name='search_assist'),`.

Comment: and your append `results.append(state_json)` should inside foor loop..

Comment: Thanks AKS. My bad. I didn't share the urls.py for the main app. Updated my question. With that, I hope the endpoint is good with that? Sanca Kembang - Yes, that is correct. Updated the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your JS call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

Comment: Thanks itzmeontv. I tried adding the ajaxSetup snippet to my JQ but it still doesn't work. Updated the question with the edit. Probably I haven't added it right. Please let me know.